# populate builder.setItem with a list<>

Tags: android, list, android-alertdialog, builder

I'm trying to build an AlertDialog using Builder. My dialog has to have multiple option the user can choose from. I found on android developers website that I can use builder.setItems(int, DialogInterface.onClickListener). my problem is that im trying to pass a List addresses instead of the int. I want the user to choose an option from the list of addresses. Here's my code for illustration:

```
    private List<Address> addresses;

    protected void updateMap() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick an Address");

    builder.setItems(addresses, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int choosenAddress) {

            //address = addresses.get(choosenAddress); //choose result from the array

        }
    });
```

In the builder.setItems ..i get an error saying this argument does not take list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetItems` takes Charsequence Array as a parameter, so you will have to convert `List<Address>` to `List<String>` and then use `list.toarray()`

Comment: I tried that.. but my Geocoder cannot store addresses in a List<String> i have to keep it as List<Address>. any suggestions?

Comment: How are you going to show addresses in a list, if you cannot convert Addresses to string? Loop over list and keep adding addresses.toString() to List<String>

Answer (score 1):

An extension to **nandeesh**'s answer

```
String [] addressStrings = new String [addresses.size()];

for(int i=0; i<addresses.size(); i++)
    addressStrings[i] = addresses.get(i).toString();
```

You need to override the `toString()` method of the `Address` class, to create meaningful `String` representations of `Address` objects.

Now in the `onClick()` method you can still access the `Address` object by the given index, because the size, and element order of the `addresses` list and the `addressStrings` array are the same.

```
Address selected = addresses.get(choosenAddress);
```